# pandas get_group causes memory error

Tags: python, pandas, out-of-memory

I have a grouped dataframe created like so:

```
my_gb = pandas.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=my_file_path,
                        delimiter='\t').groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'])
```

I then call `get_group`:

```
my_row = my_gb.get_group((val1, val2, val3, val4))
```

And get a `MemoryError`.

IIUC, this only returns a view of one row (in my dataset) - how can this cause a memory error?

Comment: Hard to tell with so little details. Might be from the loading itself. We need to know the size of the file. Plus you should divide the two operations : first load the file, then do the groupby, so we know where it's failing.

Comment: How can it be the loading itself? The memory error occurs much later as it's failing on get_group, not on reading the file or groupby.

Comment: What version of pandas are/were you using? I wonder if that's the issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't get this to work so I did the grouping myself:

```
data = pandas.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=my_file_path, delimiter='\t')
grouped = {}
for key, value in data.iterrows():
    grouped[(value['col1'], value['col2'], value['col3'], value['col4'])] = value
```