# pandas get_group memory error

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am using pandas v0.14.1 with python 2.7

I have a `groupby` object and I am trying to pull out a group identified by particular key. The key is in fact in the group:

```
>>> key in key_groups.groups.keys()
True
```

but when I try to make the `get_group` call it fails with a memory error:

```
>>>> key_groups.get_group(key)
*** MemoryError:
```

The full stacktrace is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 141, in <module>
    main(num_days=arguments.days, num_variants=arguments.variants)
  File "main.py", line 76, in main
    problem, solution = Solver.Solve(request, num_variants)
  File "/srv/compunctuator/src/Solver.py", line 49, in Solve
    solution = attempt_minimization(t)
  File "/srv/compunctuator/src/Solver.py", line 41, in attempt_minimization
    t.scruple()
  File "/srv/compunctuator/src/Compunctuator.py", line 136, in scruple
    self.__iterate__()
  File "/srv/compunctuator/src/Compunctuator.py", line 95, in __iterate__
    self.__maximize_impressions__()
  File "/srv/compunctuator/src/Compunctuator.py", line 583, in __maximize_impressions__
    df = key_groups.get_group(key)
  File "/srv/compunctuator/.virtualenvs/compunctuator/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 573, in get_group
    inds = self._get_index(name)
  File "/srv/compunctuator/.virtualenvs/compunctuator/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 429, in _get_index
    sample = next(iter(self.indices))
  File "/srv/compunctuator/.virtualenvs/compunctuator/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 414, in indices
    return self.grouper.indices
  File "properties.pyx", line 34, in pandas.lib.cache_readonly.__get__ (pandas/lib.c:36380)
  File "/srv/compunctuator/.virtualenvs/compunctuator/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1253, in indices
    return _get_indices_dict(label_list, keys)
  File "/srv/compunctuator/.virtualenvs/compunctuator/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 3474, in _get_indices_dict
    np.prod(shape))
  File "algos.pyx", line 1997, in pandas.algos.groupsort_indexer (pandas/algos.c:37521) MemoryError
```

If I actually use the dictionary lookup I can get the indices out:

```
>>>> key_groups.groups[key]
[0, 2]
```

It seems like everything should work here.

I realize a similar question was asked here [pandas get_group causes memory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28263073/pandas-get-group-causes-memory-error)
but it was never resolved and I thought I could give more details if necessary.

Comment: Upgrade your pandas, current version is 0.17.0.

Comment: But please, do give more details. Can you post a small example which demonstrates this or a link to the entire dataset? (This may be better on github though if it's a pandas issue that still an issue on master)

Comment: @AndyHayden I upgraded to 17 and I no longer see the issue. If it comes up again I will update this post.

Comment: Ok cool, voting to close but please don't delete as it's useful to have google return something when you search for this :)